# How to check if variable contains a string

Tags: c, string

My .c programme gives an object a 'name' when its created. I need to be able to excute different tasks depending on that name. I very new to this and have tried a couple of ways with no success. Here is what I had come up with..

```
if (name ==  "james"){

    //Do a bunch of stuff
    } 
if (name ==  "tom"){

    //Do a bunch of stuff
    }
```

This was not successful. Is there a way so that if the 'name' is one thing it wont execute the others?

Thankyou so much for any help

Comment: Also please don't tag C questions as C++, they are completely different languages.

Comment: Now it was tagged as C, not it's tagged as C++ again, what's going on? He said in the beginning that it's a ".c programme", so I'd assume he meant C..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C`, a string is defined as a sequence of characters which are terminated with `\0`. A string constant is normally represented within `", for example, char a[10] = "hello".

In order to compare two strings, you can use library functions like `strcmp()` which is available in `string.h`. Do `man strcmp` to read more about this function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char name[] = "tom";

        if (strcmp(name, "tom") == 0) {
            printf("name is tom! \n");
        } else if (strcmp(name, "bob") == 0) {
            printf("name is bob! \n");
        } else {
            printf("who is this?! \n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The strcmp could have been implemented in the following ways (array and pointer versions for your reference)

```
int strcmp1(char a[], char b[])
{
        int i=0;
        while (a[i] == b[i]) {
                if (a[i] == '\0')
                        return 0;
                i++;
        }

        return a[i]-b[i];
}

int strcmp2(char *a, char *b)
{
        while (*a == *b) {
                if (*a == '\0')
                        return 0;
                a++; b++;
        }
        return *a-*b;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: These implementations are both completely the same (except the use of an index of course), because you cannot pass actual arrays as function parameters; they are actually pointers as well.

Answer (score 3):

if 'name' is a C++ string, what you have written should work fine. If it's a `char[]` or `char *`, use `strcmp`.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, how would i use this with the above code?

Comment: If `name` isn't a C++ string, it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the library function [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/). When you use `==` you will just compare the pointers itself, not the actual string array lying behind them.

Comment: Not if `name` is a string, as he claims.

Comment: Well, it's quite usual to call `char*` or `char[]` "strings" in C, because "pointer to char" or "char array" just haven't the same feel.

Comment: Yes, but what is quite usual in C is sometimes very unusual in C++.  When talking about C++, "string" normally means `std::string`, and `'\0'` terminated `char*` or `char[]` will be usually be called "C-style strings" if the context isn't totally unambiguous.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the question was about C (which was kind of obvious, because if `name` were an actual `std:string`, his code were correct).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strcmp` as:

```
if (!strcmp(name,"james")){
```

Using `==` compares the contents of name(starting address of the string) with the starting address of the string literal "james" which is certainly now what you want.

Comment: `strcmp` doesn't work with C++ strings.  His problem is that he's not declared `name` with the correct type; if `name` is `std::string`, his code should work.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The question clearly talks about a `.c` file, so he is talking about C not C++.

Comment: The question was clearly tagged C++ when I looked at it.  I assumed that this meant that the question was about C++.  (I actually verified that it wasn't also tagged C before commenting.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a standard .c program, and that your 'name' is a actually a `char*` then you're going to have to use the [strings.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/string.h.html) standard c library for the the `strcmp()` function.

The equality operator `==` is for `std::string` and other string classes.

e.g.

```
if (strcmp(name,"james")==0){
  /* Do stuff */
}
```

Also, you might consider the `switch` conditional for multiple tests.

Comment: `switch` requires integral constants.  He doesn't have any of these.

Comment: Very true. I imagined his strings replaced with equivalent constants (`int JAMES=1` etc.) might be better given the seemingly fixed flow of control.